# How to add the heroku nginx buildpack to a python django app with gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, heroku, bundler, buildpack

I am trying to deploy a python with django on heroku and configure an nginx reverse proxy to have like a filter which won't let the requests pass to my django backend until the token is checked to an third party IDP.

**
**STEP 1**
**

I am following this tutorial to add the nginx buildpack : https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/hq-mobile/v3-nginx-buildpack

After I've added the buildpack and start the app, I get the following message: `bin/start-nginx: line 37: bundle: command not found`

After some digging I noticed some paths need to be added to the config vars for the heroku app in order for bundler to get the needed dependencies :

So I've added this paths:

```
heroku config:add GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle/1.9.3

heroku config:set PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Then the **config/unicorn.rb** file:

```
require 'fileutils'
listen '/tmp/nginx.socket'
before_fork do |server,worker|
  FileUtils.touch('/tmp/app-initialized')
end
```

**Procfile**:

```
web: bin/start-nginx bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py MyApp.wsgi
```

**gunicorn.conf.py**

```
# gunicorn.conf
def when_ready(server):
    # touch app-initialized when ready
    open('/tmp/app-initialized', 'w').close()

bind = 'unix:///tmp/nginx.socket'
workers = 4
```

*Even after adding this, the error still persists.*

**
**STEP 2**
**

Once the normal buildpack will be in place I want to follow this tutorial to configure nginx how I want:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/validating-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-nginx/

What configuration is needed to be able to have this buildpack working in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, you remove the `bundle exec` part from the Procfile. In other words, your Procfile becomes:

```sh
web: bin/start-nginx unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py MyApp.wsgi
```

(sidenote: there might be an error with just using `MyApp.wsgi` since you **might** need to change it to something like `MyApp.wsgi:application` to expose the environment variable for your application)